# How to know if a stage is rejected by environment in Azure Pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

There is a deployment job we can define environment for approval. I have pipeline where a stageA contain a deployment job with an environment for approval check and some other normal jobs.

I also have stageB depends on stageA. and I want to trigger this stageB only when the deployment job in stageA is rejected by the environment approval check. So in case of failure of other normal jobs in stageA should not trigger stageB.

```yaml
trigger:
    - none
pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
stages:
    - stage: stageA
      jobs:
          - deployment: main_job
            environment: "myenv"
            strategy:
                runOnce:
                    deploy:
                        steps:
                            - script: echo "Env_Check pass"
                              displayName: "Env_Check"
          - job: other_job
            dependsOn: main_job
            steps:
                - script: exit 1;
                  displayName: "failure task"
    - stage: stageB
      dependsOn: stageA
      condition: 'what condition should we put here??'
      jobs:
          - job:
            steps:
                - script: echo "Env-Check Rejected"
                  displayName: "approval_reject"
```

How can we do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During my local test, I suppose that you could edit your yaml as below. Both reject or cancellation will run the next stage correctly.

***Updated on Oct. 5th***
**=============================================================**
I referred to this document and updated the yaml below.
[Deployment job output variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#deployment-job-output-variables)

```
trigger:
    - none
pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
stages:
    - stage: stageA
      jobs:
          - deployment: main_job
            environment: "myenv"
            strategy:
                runOnce:
                    deploy:
                        steps:
                            
                            - script: echo "Env_Check pass"
                              displayName: "Env_Check"
                            - task: PowerShell@2
                              name: setRunTests
                              inputs:
                                targetType: inline
                                pwsh: true
                                script: |
                                  $runTests = "true"
                                  echo "setting runTests: $runTests"
                                  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runTests;isOutput=true]$runTests"
          - job: other_job
            dependsOn: main_job
            steps:
                - script: exit 1;
                  displayName: "failure task"

  
    - stage: stageB
      dependsOn: stageA
      condition: and(failed(),ne(dependencies.stageA.outputs['main_job.main_job.setRunTests.runTests'], 'true'))
      jobs:
          - job:
            steps:
                - script: echo "Env-Check Rejected"
                  displayName: "approval_reject"
```

***Env_Approved***

[image]

***Env_Rejected***

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but what if your Env_Check stage contains one more normal job below the deployment job which depends on the deployment job. If this normal job fail, the Reject_confirmed will still be triggered I believe. I only want the Reject_confirmed triggered when the deployment job is rejected by approval check.

Comment: I add a pipeline in the question to describe it

Comment: @ikhvjs you could check my latest update